# How do I configure PHP_LDAP on a Centos box to securely connect with an Active Directory to set passwords

Tags: ssl, active-directory, centos7, openldap

This is a variation / evolution of an existing question.

I have inherited an Active Directory server.
I had LDAP read access. I have now set up an LDAP modify user to allow me to modify the AD.
I can create / modify users but I cannot set passwords or enable accounts.
I have created a security certificate, and exported a BASE64 .cer file.
I have copied the .cer to my linux box and added

TLS_CACERT  /etc/openldap/certs/LDAPUpdate.cer

to /etc/openldap/ldap.conf

I have checked the server using nmap and the ldapSSL port 636 is open to my linux box

If I connect using ldap://  either using the cli tools or php_ldap it works
If I connect using ldaps:// I get connection failed:

The actual output is below (with lots of debug turned on).
It looks like it is making the connection and trying to start tls/ssl but failing. It does not reference my certificate file at all.

[user@centos cli]$ ./ADSearch.php kathy
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://localhost/)
ldap_init: trying /etc/openldap/ldap.conf
ldap_init: using /etc/openldap/ldap.conf
ldap_init: HOME env is /home/httpd
ldap_init: trying /home/httpd/ldaprc
ldap_init: trying /home/httpd/.ldaprc
ldap_init: LDAPCONF env is NULL
ldap_init: LDAPRC env is NULL
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://.)
ldap_sasl_bind_s
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP .:636
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying :636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
TLSMC: MozNSS compatibility interception begins.
tlsmc_intercept_initialization: INFO: entry options follow:
tlsmc_intercept_initialization: INFO: cacertdir = `/etc/openldap/cacerts' tlsmc_intercept_initialization: INFO: certfile =` (null)'
tlsmc_intercept_initialization: INFO: keyfile = `(null)' tlsmc_convert: INFO: trying to open NSS DB with CACertDir =` /etc/openldap/cacerts'.
tlsmc_open_nssdb: INFO: trying to initialize moznss using security dir `/etc/openldap` prefix `cacerts`.
tlsmc_open_nssdb: WARN: could not initialize MozNSS context - error -8015.
tlsmc_convert: INFO: cannot open the NSS DB, expecting PEM configuration is present.
tlsmc_intercept_initialization: INFO: altered options follow:
tlsmc_intercept_initialization: INFO: cacertdir = `/etc/openldap' tlsmc_intercept_initialization: INFO: certfile =` (null)'
tlsmc_intercept_initialization: INFO: keyfile = `(null)'
tlsmc_intercept_initialization: INFO: successfully intercepted TLS initialization. Continuing with OpenSSL only.
TLSMC: MozNSS compatibility interception ends.
TLS trace: SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
TLS trace: SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 write client hello B
TLS: can't connect: .
ldap_err2string